# Carregar paginas sem refresh ao clica na opção de menu

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, angularjs

Boa Noite galera! Estou fazendo um sistema de escola, nele vai ter niveis de acesso, menu para cada acesso. Quero fazer o seguinte, quando eu clicar em alguma opção do menu lateral, onde esta escrito "BLANK" na parte do meio, quero que apareça a pagina correspondente, sem mudar de pagina. Enfim, fiz umas aplicações anteriores com ajax, mas não ficou tão bom, ouvi falar no Angular e tal, vocês poderiam me dar um rumo? Se só dá para fazer com ajax, ou o angular serve para isso? Pois nao entendi muito bem o que ele faz, e se existe framework para isso, desde já, obrigado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom, angular eu não sei. Mas se quiser com ajax, eu faço uma resposta

Comment: Isso que você está falando é fazer um [Single Page Applicaiton](https://www.codeschool.com/beginners-guide-to-web-development/single-page-applications). O Angular é um ótimo framework para isso. Nós temos 2 Angular:  o **AngularJS**, que foi a primeira versão, e o **Angular**, que é totalmente diferente do seu antecessor mas muito mais complicado (Ao meu ver) Aparentemente você não entende muito sobre isso, então conselho ir pelo AngularJS que é mais simples. Inicie algum projeto utilizando Angular e [AngularJS Routing](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) e poste dúvidas =)

Comment: [sugiro que veja esse vídeo](https://youtu.be/AljlfNqZp_E)

Comment: Obrigado galera!!! Vou ver o vídeo e tentar fazer a Single Page

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não precisa de tanto, amigo. Via javascript você consegue o que precisa de forma rápida e sem a necessidade de plugins. A solução passa por encapsular cada página em uma DIV e controlar a propriedade "display" alternando entre visível e invisível conforme a ação do usuário sobre o menu. Tudo ficará em uma única página que será mostrada onde está escrito "blank", porém somente o conteúdo de uma DIV aparecerá por vez.

```
function toggle(nome_da_div, estado) {
        var display = document.getElementById(nome_da_div).style.display;
        document.getElementById(nome_da_div).style.display = estado;
    }
```

Ao clicar em um item de menu você pode chamar a função acima para alterar a visibilidade da DIV:

```
toggle('div-nome-tal', 'block'); // visível
toggle('div-nome-tal', 'none'); // invisível
```

Esta é a maneira mais simples de fazer. Contudo, se quiser usar um plugin, sugiro que pesquise sobre Bootstrap que tem uma série de recursos prontos para isso:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Comment: Obrigado!! Vou implementar essa solução

Comment: Pelo que entendi da questão, a página não seria 100% carregada a priori, mas sim a sua estrutura com a parte dos menus. Creio que, além do _toggle_ de aparecer e sumir, seria adequado por na sua resposta o como tratar a requisição ajax de modo a inserir o conteúdo dinamicamente nas `div`s adequadas. Também guardaria quem está sendo exibido no membro para que, eu mandar exibir as informações de algo do menu, se ocultasse automaticamente o item selecionado anteriormente, mas esse último detalhe é mais um preciosismo para evitar bugs/diminuir a manutenção do que algo que responda a questão